# Заполнение массива случайными числами в диапазоне (A, B) и определить кол-во элементов, у которых вторая цифра четная

Tags: python

**Вот задача:**

Напишите программу, которая заполняет массив из N элементов случайными целыми числами в диапазоне [ A , B ] и определяет количество элементов этого массива, у которых вторая цифра в десятичной записи (число десятков) – чётная.

*Входные данные:*
Входная строка содержит три числа: границы диапазона случайных чисел A и B , а также размер массива N . Все числа разделены пробелами. Гарантируется, что 0 < N ≤ 10000 .

*Выходные данные:*
В первой строке программа должна вывести N элементов построенного массива, разделив их пробелами, а во второй строке – число элементов этого массива, у которых вторая цифра в десятичной записи (число десятков) – чётная.

**Вот мой код:**

```
import random
mas=[]
k = 0
a, b, n = map(int,input().split())
for i in range(n):
    mas.append(random.randint(a, b))
    print(mas[i], end=' ')
    if(mas[i] >=10):
        if (((mas[i] // 10) % 10) % 2 == 0):
            k += 1
print()
print(k)
```

Программа работает корректно, но сайт решение не принимает. Что можно изменить, чтобы программа работала быстрее?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю нужна проверка введенного диапазона. Если я введу диапазон 0 1000. Например сгенерирует 4, тогда ((4 // 10) % 10) % 2 == 0 будет True и Ваш код выполнит k += 1

Comment: Точно) Я как-то упустил этот момент)

Comment: хмм.. добавил проверку:

 if(mas[i] >=10):
        if (((mas[i] // 10) % 10) % 2 == 0):
            k += 1

Но сайт всё равно не принимает решение

Comment: А какой сайт? Скорее всего имеется ввиду написать функцию которая должна вернуть количество таких елементов в массиве. (но это не точно)

Comment: informatics.mccme
Про функцию там ничего не сказано

Comment: А можно ссылку конкретно на задачу? И еще  не обезательно искать остаток от деления. Если убрать "% 10" то поведение программы не изменится.

Comment: https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=46396&chapterid=112277#1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
k = 0
a,b,n = map(int,input().split())
mas = [random.randint(a,b) for i in range (n)]
for i in range (n):
    if int(mas[i] / 10) % 10 % 2 == 0:
        k+=1
print(*mas)
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте совсем сменить логику. не факт что быстрее, но другой подход:

```
import random
def solve2(a,b,n):
    k = 0
    mas=[]
    for i in range(n):
        mas.append(random.randint(a, b))

    for z in mas:
         z_str = str(z)
         if len(z_str)>1:
             if z_str[-2] in {'0','2','4','6','8'}:
                 k+=1
    print(*mas)
    return (k,mas)


k,mas = solve2(a,b,n)
print()
print(k)
```

Comment: Всё равно не принимает(

Comment: @Slad  - приведите полное условие задачи с сайта.